# ImportError: cannot import name 'comb'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am using the updated scikit-learn version 0.18.1 but still I am getting the 
ImportError: cannot import name 'comb' when I try to use the model_selection.

Using Spyder IDE latest version.

Comment: Edit the question to include the full error traceback message, explain how you installed the scikit module, and explain how you run the code.

Comment: The answer in [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46178199/python-sklearn-model-selection-giving-error-unable-to-import-comb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46178199/python-sklearn-model-selection-giving-error-unable-to-import-comb)solved my problem.